# Why can a defunct company still be assigned an IP address/IP address range by ARIN?

Tags: ip-address, whois

Basically, I'm looking at the Whois record of an IP address and the organization listed is a defunct company acquired in the late 1990s. The Whois record was updated last year, so why is the defunct company still listed in the record?

Comment: Since this is a policy decision made by ARIN, it's likely that only they can answer this – at least as long as you don't provide the specific example that we could make better guesses about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, grawity -- I can't share the specific example.

Comment: Hi, sorry for it being off-topic. Which StackExchange site would be more appropriate? StackOverflow?

Comment: Most likely none at all – maybe Network Engineering but even that's a stretch. Try e.g. NANOG mailing list instead, where many people at least have plenty of experience with how ARIN operates. But even they will want to know which address range it is, as the reason can vary greatly depending on the allocation's origins.